# popup a message every hour in the browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am new to JavaScript and trying to build a simple web application.
My requirement is that after I start the timer, I need the application to popup with a message.

**Edit:** Note that the user might not be viewing this webpage and if so, it is mandatory to be display it so that the user notices it, something similar to bringing to front in windows

The reason why I'm asking is that this is very simple and can be implemented already in some frameworks. I googled and found there are so many implementations for timers, but not to show popup messages. I don't need sample code but if you can give some directions like where to start it will be nice.

I call this an application, because the thought process is to improve this in future to bring a window which allows user to write something rather than just showing popup message.

How can I make it happen?
What frameworks can I use?
Can you show me a simple application following my approach?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` and run a function that displays `alert`

Comment: Not certain what question is?

Comment: you can use `setInterval `

Comment: @Tareq Thank you. I will give a try and will update.

Answer (score 1):

You can start and stop your interval on click like this

```
$(function() {
    var timer = null, 
        interval = 1000 * 60 * 60;

    $("#start").click(function() {
      if (timer !== null) return;
      timer = setInterval(function () {
          alert("okay");
      }, interval); 
    });

    $("#stop").click(function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = null
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have localStorage, you can create a simple **persistent** JS timer:

```
//  ensure u have localStorage (can be done better).
if (localStorage)
{
    //  get the localStorage variable.
    let timerValue = localStorage.getItem('timerValue');

  //  if it's not set yet, set it.
  if (!timerValue)
  {
    timerValue = new Date().toString();
    localStorage.setItem('timerValue', timerValue);
  }

  //  parse string date and get difference between now - old time in milliseconds.
  let diff = new Date().getTime() - new Date(timerValue).getTime();

  //  compare difference and check if it matches 1 hour (1000ms * 60s * 60m)
  if (diff >= 1000 * 60 * 60)
  {
    //  reset timer immediately.
    localStorage.setItem('timerValue', new Date().toString());

    // do something..
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Edit: and if you want the timer to update realtime, you can, like mentioned use setInterval

Edit 2: I got a like, so I improved my code a bit:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="timer"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
const AmountOfTimeToCheckInMs = 1000 * 60 * 60;
const PollingSpeedInMs        = 1000;

class PersistentTimer
{
  constructor()
  {
    //  ensure u have localStorage (can be done better).
    if (!localStorage)
    {
      console.log('localStorage not supported!');
      return;
    }

    //  get the timer element.
    this.timerElement = document.querySelector('#timer');

    //  get the localStorage variable.
    this.timerValue = localStorage.getItem('timerValue');

    //  if it's not set yet, set it.
    if (!this.timerValue)
    {
      this.resetTimer();
    }

    this.updateTimer();
    setInterval(() => this.triggerEverySecond(), PollingSpeedInMs);
  }

  triggerEverySecond()
  {
    this.updateTimer();

    //  compare difference and check if it matches 1 hour (1000ms * 60s * 60m)
    if (this.getTimeDifference() >= AmountOfTimeToCheckInMs)
    {
      //  reset timer immediately.
      this.resetTimer();

      // do something..
    }
  }

  resetTimer()
  {
    this.timerValue = new Date().toString();

    localStorage.setItem('timerValue', this.timerValue);
  }

  getTimeDifference()
  {
    //  parse string date and get difference between now - old time in milliseconds.
    return new Date().getTime() - new Date(this.timerValue).getTime();
  }

  updateTimer()
  {
    let calculatedDiffDate = new Date()
    calculatedDiffDate.setTime(AmountOfTimeToCheckInMs - this.getTimeDifference());

    this.timerElement.innerHTML = calculatedDiffDate.getMinutes() + 'm ' + calculatedDiffDate.getSeconds() + 's';
  }
}

new PersistentTimer();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pwd46259/

Comment: Nice idea for persistent timers across pages, but if the user stays on the same page for a long time, you'd still need to implement an interval/timeout on top of this.

Comment: Yes you are right, i edited and added that you can use the interval to poll for updates.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a function to call it every hour with setInterval

```
setInterval(yourFunction, 1000 * 60 * 60);
```

In your function you can build a pop your self..
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

or you can simply call an alert()....

Comment: Would not recommend using the alert() function though, as it pauses the interval until it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

you need use js function setTimeout(yourFunc, timeDelay) [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/timers), yourFunc should change css property or change css class, ***display: none***, ***display: block*** (or other). [My example](https://codepen.io/maksyukvadim/pen/ZXrWwP) show message after 2s.

```js
const popUp = document.getElementById('popUp');

setTimeout(() => {
  popUp.style.display = 'flex';
}, 2000);
```

```css
#popUp {
  positon: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}
#message {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='popUp'>
  <div id='message'>
    hellow
  </div>
</div>
```